# Extracting all emails from text data

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported the data file:

```py
import pandas as pd

em = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\notepad\film.csv' ,error_bad_lines=False)
```

The code is not working, does anyone has any better code?

```py
import numpy as np

em['email'] = em['Actors & Actresses Address']
nan_rows = em[em.isnull().any(1)]
em = em.fillna(' ')
nan_rows = em[em.isnull().any(1)]

for word in em:
    new = []
    i = ".com"
    if i in word:
        new.append(word)
        em.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)

print(new)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add couple of examples of how your 'Actor & Actresses Address' column look like. You can try regex search to filter out the email in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

what about trying this:

```
d = {"Movie": ["Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3"], "e-mail":["not an e-mail ad","mail@yahoo.com", "mail@gmail.com"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["e-mail"][df["e-mail"].apply(lambda x: "@" in x)]
```

Alternatively:

```
df["e-mail"][df['e-mail'].str.contains('@')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
em['Actors & Actresses Address'].fillna("").str.extract("([\w_.]+@[\w_.]+.com)")
```